# Writing an aspectj pointcut for java.io.FileOutputStream

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I would like to write a pointcut for the `new FileInputstream(File file)` constructor.
For example,
a common way to create a new file in java is:

```
File file = new File(myDirectory, "myFileName.txt");
new FileOutputStream(file);
```

What I've tried so far is this:

Inside `FileCreation.aj`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

aspect FileCreation {

    pointcut FileOutputStream1(File file): call(FileOutputStream FileOutputStream(File)) && args(file);
    FileOutputStream around(File file): FileOutputStream1(file) {
        System.out.println("I was called!!");
        return proceed(file);
    }

}
```

In order to test whether this hook is working, I added a print statement.

However, it seems like this isn't getting invoked.

Not sure what the mistake is in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is invalid constructor call syntax. You need to use `.new` and no return type specifier, because the return type implicitly is always the class of the intercepted constructor.

BTW, be careful not to name methods like classes. Better use `fileOutputStream1` with a lower-case "f" as a pointcut name. Otherwise, your code is difficult to read.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

aspect FileCreation {
  pointcut fileOutputStream1(File file) :
    call(FileOutputStream.new(File)) &&
    args(file);

  FileOutputStream around(File file) : fileOutputStream1(file) {
    System.out.println("I was called!!");
    return proceed(file);
  }
}
```